# how to add default text to combo box in windows forms before binding

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

My code below binds the list of properties which it will get by calling method GetProperties, to PropertyCombo(ComboBox)

```
List<String> properties = CiaLogicObj.GetProperties(classComboSelectedIndex);

BindingSource binSource = new BindingSource();

binSource.DataSource = properties;

PropertyCombo.DataSource = binSource;
```

Before binding, I want my `ComboBox` to show "<please Select>" as first item in it.
I am not able to do it.
Below methods are not working.

`PropertyCombo.text="<please Select>"`
or 
`PropertyCombo.Items.Insert(0,"<please Select>")`

Answer (score 0):

Define a class as

```
 public class ComboboxItem
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

consider your combobox ddlService

```
ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
                item.Text = "Select Service";
                item.Value = -1;
                ddlService.Items.Add(item);

                           or
You can set default value in combobox collections in Items property.
```

Comment: Errors are coming:-                                              Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

Once you set the binding, the `ComboBox` is going to display the content to which is bound.  The way to set a "default" item would be to insert an item at the beginning of the list:

```
List<String> properties = new List<String>();
properties.Add("<please Select");
foreach (String str in CiaLogicObj.GetProperties(classComboSelectedIndex))
    properties.Add(str);

BindingSource binSource = new BindingSource();

binSource.DataSource = properties;

PropertyCombo.DataSource = binSource;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
List<String> properties = CiaLogicObj.GetProperties(classComboSelectedIndex);

properties.Insert(0, "<please Select>");

BindingSource binSource = new BindingSource();
binSource.DataSource = properties;
PropertyCombo.DataSource = binSource;
```

Answer (score 0):

First add required value to list `properties` and then add one by one items from list to `PropertyCombo`. Finally set [`SelectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of `PropertyCombo` to `0`, like this:

```
List<String> properties = CiaLogicObj.GetProperties(classComboSelectedIndex);
properties.Insert(0,"<Select Value>");

foreach(var item in properties)
   PropertyCombo.Items.Add(item);

PropertyCombo.SelectedIndex = 0;
```